# Mid/late '80s paperback about a boy on a space station who steals a shuttle to visit a devastated Earth

Tags: story-identification, novel, soft-sci-fi

Humans are living on a space station orbiting Earth (or possibly a colony on the Moon). They are forbidden to go down to the planet because there had been some kind of cataclysm (war, plague, or what have you) years/decades/centuries ago. A boy and his pet disobeyed the rules and stole a craft and went down to the surface where they met a girl and had all sorts of misadventures.

I read this book in the mid/late-'80s. I remember it being geared toward younger teen-aged readers and not written by a well known author. It was in English and I recall the cover being a picture of the boy and his pet in the shuttle with Earth in the window.

Comment: Also posted to https://www.sffchronicles.com/threads/580049/