# I'm looking for a book titled "Signal to Space" which was translated from a French novel titled "Le Signal" originally published in the 1970's

Tags: story-identification, soft-sci-fi

I read this book in the mid 1980's. It revolves around a young boy and his pet. In the story, humans live in a space station orbiting Earth after a cataclysmic event has rendered the planet uninhabitable. The inhabitants of the space station are strictly forbidden from returning to Earth's surface.
However, the boy and his pet defy these rules and embark on a journey to the planet's surface, where they encounter a young girl and face various challenges and adventures.

Comment: If you know the title, why do you need to identify it?

Comment: The ISFDB doesn't list a book titled either _Le Signal_ or _Signal to Space_.

Comment: I was unable to find any info on the book myself, which is why I tried here. It's seeming likely that I have horribly misremembered the title. The plot I listed is what I remember though, so it seems I have to start over on figuring out the actual book.

Comment: Is that the same book that [you asked about two years ago](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/251352/98028)? If so, please don't ask a new question, instead edit the previous question with any additional details. The two questions sound very very much alike and I'd propose to close as duplicate, but having a "close hammer" for these I don't want to do this unilaterally while there's no answer to any.